# Fetching data from LDAP active directory by using id?

Tags: active-directory, jndi, ldap-query

I want to fetch some user information from LDAP Active directory by using Id.
here is the code I'm trying to connect and fetch it.

```
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search("DC=erieinsurance,DC=com", "(&(objectCategory=user)(name{0}))", 
                    new Object[]{Id}, // filter arguments
                ctls); // search controls
            }
if (results.hasMoreElements()) {

}
```

it is returning no correspnding values of givenname and sn.

Is there anything wrong in the above filter?
any suggestions around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you are using JNDI.

Here is a small sample

```
//Create the initial directory context
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);

//Create the search controls
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();

//Specify the attributes to return
String returnedAtts[]={"distinguishedName","CN","sAMAccountName"};
ctls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);

//Specify the search scope
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

//specify the LDAP search filter
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName="+ theUserToCheck +"))";

//Specify the Base for the search
String searchBase = "DC=erieinsurance,DC=com";

//initialize counter to total the results
int totalResults = 0;

//Search for objects using the filter
NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search(searchBase, searchFilter, ctls);

//Loop through the search results
while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
    totalResults++;
    System.out.println(totalResults + ". " + sr.getName().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...yes, we are using JNDI. It is resolved now the search parameter Id was mapped to different parameter, now I have mapped to 'CN'..so it is working...

Comment: "theUserToCheck" is vulnarable to LDAP filter injection, e.g. if someone specifies theUserToCheck = "*)(otherAttr=otherValue"